# VS13 won't build all changes

Tags: c#, build, visual-studio-2013

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Professional.

When I do a "build", VS won't build all the changes I made in my solution. Only when I hit "rebuild" or "clean and build", my changes are compiled correctly. Even when I just set a breakpoint and build, it says the breakpoint can't be hit. I know I can just reset F6 to execute a rebuild, but because I have a big solution, this would always take about 10 seconds, even for the smallest changes..

This is a problem other people have faced, and there are a few steps suggested to fix it. These don't work in my case though.
 •Yes, I've set "On run, when projects are out of date" to "Always build" or "Prompt to build", both didn't work.
 •Yes, I've checked the build configurations manager that all projects are checked to build.

I have a feeling that it's still something in my settings.. WhenA few weeks ago I was still using Visual Studio 2012, and I had the same problem. Now in my company, I got VS13, and because of some specific settings they used my VS12 settings file to maintain them. Only one other person in our IT-department has that problem, so the general company settings are not the problem. I can't recall changing anything on my own though..

So, did anybody find another way to solve this problem besides the 2 tips I listed above ?

Comment: Inside options in debugging general have you got require source files to exactly match the original checked?

Comment: Do you have the project dependencies set up in your solution? In order to hope for the correct behavior of the 'Build' command you have to make sure that one of projects marked as "Startup" has a dependency on the project which you have changed and need to be actually rebuilt. I am not sure that this is enough but I am sure that without project dependencies the missing rebuild problem happens way more often.

Comment: @ZoomVirus : Yes, that's checked.

Comment: @zverev.eugene : Yes the startup project is dependent on the project I made the changes in. When I view the build order, my changed project comes first, then the startup project.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check skipped source files modified timestamps. Incremental build compares timestamps in input and output files: [MSDN Incremental build link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171483.aspx).
Also you can set msbuild output level to `Diagnostic` in Tools -> Option -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run and see more detailed output.